# Error on converting UnityScript to C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am trying to convert some UnityScript code to D# and I am getting the following error:

> Expression denotes a method group, where a `variable`, `value` or `type` was expected on the Getcomponent

```
void  Update ()
{
    float xVel = GetComponent().Rigidbody2D().velocity.x;
    if( xVel < 18 && xVel > -18 && xVel !=0){
        if(xVel > 0){
            GetComponent.Rigidbody2D().velocity.x=20;   

        }else{
            GetComponent.Rigidbody2D().velocity.x = -20;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You try to assign `xVel` actually?

Comment: Show us the code for GetComponent.

Comment: Getomponet is an inbuilt method in unity http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is with: `GetComponent().Rigidbody2D()` as that is not how you use GetComponent, the error you are seeing is probably because `GetComponent` requires a parameter or a specified type. The JS and C# GetComponent work a little different. You probably mean to do:

```
void  Update ()
{
    float xVel = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x;
    if( xVel < 18 && xVel > -18 && xVel !=0){
        if(xVel > 0){
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x = 20;   

        }else{
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x = -20;

        }
    }
}
```

Also in C#, I don't think you can modify the velocity directly, due to the property wrappers around it. Instead you have to manually update the velocity to a new `Vector2`. If you only want to set the `x` value, pass in the existing `y` value.

I would write it something like this:

```
private Rigidbody2D _rigidBody;

void Start()
{
    _rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void  Update ()
{
    float xVel = _rigidBody.velocity.x;
    if( xVel < 18 && xVel > -18 && xVel !=0){
        if(xVel > 0){
            _rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(20, _rigidBody.velocity.y);   

        }else{
            _rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(-20, _rigidBody.velocity.y);   
        }
    }
}
```

Though I'd change that magic `18` in to a variable too but I can't make a guess here as to what it represents!

Comment: It still gives me this error : Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D.velocity'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable

Comment: I think velocity cannot be modified manually. You will need to do: `_rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(newXHere, _rigidBody.velocity.y);`

Comment: sorry to bother you but you have been really helpful i am getting an error about this code _rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(y/2, _rigidBody.velocity.x) + colInfo.collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y/3;
its saying The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Vector2.Vector2(float, float)' has some invalid arguments and  Argument `#1' cannot convert `object' expression to type `float'

Comment: That's because you're trying to add the left hand side, which is a `Vector2` to just `y/3` which is a float. Totally assuming here that you mean: `_rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(y/2, _rigidBody.velocity.x) + new Vector2(0, colInfo.collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y/3);` I may have got the x/y the wrong way round but that's the best guess I can make.

Comment: and again :( :
 1.The name `y' does not exist in the current context ,
2.The best overloaded method match for 3.`UnityEngine.Vector2.Vector2(float, float)' has some invalid arguments
Argument `#1' cannot convert `object' expression to type `float'

Comment: I assumed Y was defined as it was in your code. I cannot fix that bit as I have no idea what Y should be in that context. Your other issues are simply changing those `y/2` and `y/3` to `y/2f` and `y/3f` probably.

Answer (score 2):

```
float xVel = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x;
```

GetComponent is used like this.